# I am confused understanding these sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

1. He was watching me playing guitar.
2. He was watching me played guitar.
3. He was watching me play guitar.

What type of sentences are these?
Also, how to decide which one is correct?

Comment: Can you indicate where you have found these sentences?

Comment: I was watching a movie and there I listened to someone saying, "He was watching me played guitar". Since then I have been struggling to find what type of sentence is this and other alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *He was watching me played guitar.

This sentence is incorrect. The construction is ***to watch someone DO/DOING something***.

The rule is something like this: if you saw the complete action you use DO:

> I saw him fall off the wall.

Otherwise you use DOING:

> I watched him playing guitar.

So, depending on what you want to emphasise, sentences 1 and 3 can be used.

You can always read more on the subject on the [personlongman](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00066.htm) site.